# I need help in Code in Selenium with Java regarding If else condition

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng

**strong text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ret.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK661.jpg)

I need help in Code in Selenium with Java regarding If else..
I have two WebElements as first is "//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]" and second one is "//div//span[contains(text(),'Grid Report saved successfully.')]" So i need here is that if first element matches with the text "Report name already exists. Please enter another name." then do the rest part of the code and if second element is matching with the text "Grid Report saved successfully.", then do the another part of coding part. I trired with if else condition but it is not working.. please any one have any idea then please share..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native element to check if the element is present you can use :

**create a function:**

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by){
        try{
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and now call it in your if case:

```
 if(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]")))
   {
       //code
   }
   else if(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Grid Report saved successfully.')]")))
   {
       //code
   }
```

**Second option:**

```
List<WebElement> element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]"));
   List<WebElement> element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Grid Report saved successfully.')]"));

   if(!element1.isEmpty() )
   {
       //first set of code
   }
   else if(!element2.isEmpty())
   {
       //second set of code
   }
```

second option has more processing so first one is more recommended

Answer for your question:

```
         List < WebElement > ifPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]"));
         if (!ifPresent.isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("Use this one");
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnClose']")).click();
         } else {
             System.out.println("Use this one else");
             Set<String> handles=driver.getWindowHandles();
             
             driver.switchTo().window((String) handles.toArray()[1]);
             
             scrollPageUpByRobotClass();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnAlertOk']")).click();
             driver.switchTo().window((String) handles.toArray()[0]);
         }
```

Comment: @AmolPardhi could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign, if this helped

Comment: I tried with both the answers, sorry but it did not worked.. The code is getting printed in console is the if part and not getting in the else if part..

Comment: you have to use not (! ) so that you do something if its present

Comment: Actually the problem i got to understand is that in the UI if i try to make new report from UI and click on Ok button new windows gets open with text as Grid Report saved successfully.

Comment: you can use getWindowshandles and do switch_to  windows you want . google it to see how to switch in python selenium

Comment: List<WebElement> ifPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]"));
     if(!ifPresent.isEmpty())
     {
         System.out.println("Use this one");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnClose']")).click();
     }
     else if(ifPresent.isEmpty())
     {
         System.out.println("Use this one else");
         driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
         scrollPageUpByRobotClass();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnAlertOk']")).click();
     }

Comment: Just one problem is that when the code gets in else if part.. The code waits like 1 or 2 minutes hung and after that it does the other stuff in else if part..

Comment: Is element1 and element2  in same window ?

Comment: element1 is in same window and element2 get generated in another window..

Comment: @Amol you can accept only one answer , accept the one which is helpful

Comment: ok.. i didnt knew this.. I am new to ask question in this platform. N thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @AmolPardhi added answer see if it helps

Comment: Please let me know

Comment: I have one String as "View 1 - 20 of 1,456".  So here in need 1456 number in console.. I Tried with one code  String str = "View 1 - 20 of 1,456";
  String newString[] = str.split(" of ");
  String Count = newString[1];
  String finalCount = Count.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
  System.out.println(finalCount);  and when i run the code sometimes it gets error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.

Comment: I have included this code in selenium script.. so error is getting as java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: if its sometimes then make sure your string variable is not empty , please ask as a different question if you have more doubts

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct try the below code it should work. if not please post your code to fix the issue.

```
 WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Report name already exists. Please enter another name.')]"));
   WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Grid Report saved successfully.')]"));
   
   if(element1.isDisplayed())
   {
       //first set of code
   }
   else if(element2.isDisplayed())
   {
       //second set of code
   }
```

Comment: Thanks selladurai for this answer.. I used this type of code but it not worked..